# Distance of normal to the ellipse from the centre of the circle

Tags: optimization, analytic-geometry, circles, conic-sections, maxima-minima

Find the normals to the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$ which are farthest from the centre.

My approach

Let the point be $(x_1 ,y_1)$ and the tangent equation is $\frac{xx_1}{9}+\frac{yy_1}{4}=1$

Let the point be $(x_1 ,y_1)$ and the normal equation be  $\frac{xy_1}{4}-\frac{yx_1}{9}=\frac{x_1y_1}{4}-\frac{x_1y_1}{9}=\frac{5x_1y_1}{36}$

The equation reduced to $9xy_1-4yx_1=5x_1y_1$, not able to proceed from here

Comment: Try writing the equation of the ellipse in parametric form. That should lead to a single-variable function for the distance that you can maximize using the usual techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Now, let $x_1=a$ and $y_1=b$.

Thus, the distance from the normal to the origin it's
$$\frac{5|ab|}{\sqrt{16a^2+81b^2}}$$ or after homogenization it's 
$$\frac{5|ab|}{\sqrt{(16a^2+81b^2)\left(\frac{a^2}{9}+\frac{b^2}{4}\right)}}.$$
We'll prove that the maximal value of the last expression is $2$.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\frac{5|ab|}{\sqrt{(16a^2+81b^2)\left(\frac{a^2}{9}+\frac{b^2}{4}\right)}}\leq2$$ or
$$(16a^2+81b^2)(4a^2+9b^2)\geq900a^2b^2$$ or
$$(8a^2-27b^2)^2\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

An equality occurs for $8a^2-27b^2=0$, which says that $2$ is a maximal value and it'a remains to solve the following system:
$$8a^2=27b^2,$$ 
$$\frac{a^2}{9}+\frac{b^2}{4}=1$$ and to write an equations of the normals.